# When I try to upload my App Bundle in Google Play Console I get the error: "The following content provider authorities are in use by other developers"

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-play-console, react-native-firebase

When I try to upload my App Bundle in Google Play Console I get the following error:

"Remove conflicts from the manifest before uploading. The following content provider authorities are in use by other developers: com.####.firebaseinitprovider, com.####.reactnativefirebaseappinitprovider."

[image]

Searching online, I discovered that I should change the name in my "AndroidManifest.xml"
but my AndroidManifest does not contain any provider with that name

My AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
```

I tried adding a provider like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <provider
        android:name="com.example.firebaseinitprovider"
        android:authorities="com.example.myapp.provider"
        android:exported="false">
  </provider>
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
```

But if I do this my app doesn't start anymore, I'm probably doing something wrong.

The official documentation where I use the library makes no mention of this problem or how to do it.
Library I use: https://rnfirebase.io

What should I do to solve the problem?

I also insert my build.gradle if needed:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

/**
 * This is the configuration block to customize your React Native Android app.
 * By default you don't need to apply any configuration, just uncomment the lines you need.
 */
react {
    /* Folders */
    //   The root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives. Default is '..'
    // root = file("../")
    //   The folder where the react-native NPM package is. Default is ../node_modules/react-native
    // reactNativeDir = file("../node_modules/react-native")
    //   The folder where the react-native Codegen package is. Default is ../node_modules/@react-native/codegen
    // codegenDir = file("../node_modules/@react-native/codegen")
    //   The cli.js file which is the React Native CLI entrypoint. Default is ../node_modules/react-native/cli.js
    // cliFile = file("../node_modules/react-native/cli.js")

    /* Variants */
    //   The list of variants to that are debuggable. For those we're going to
    //   skip the bundling of the JS bundle and the assets. By default is just 'debug'.
    //   If you add flavors like lite, prod, etc. you'll have to list your debuggableVariants.
    // debuggableVariants = ["liteDebug", "prodDebug"]

    /* Bundling */
    //   A list containing the node command and its flags. Default is just 'node'.
    // nodeExecutableAndArgs = ["node"]
    //
    //   The command to run when bundling. By default is 'bundle'
    // bundleCommand = "ram-bundle"
    //
    //   The path to the CLI configuration file. Default is empty.
    // bundleConfig = file(../rn-cli.config.js)
    //
    //   The name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
    // bundleAssetName = "MyApplication.android.bundle"
    //
    //   The entry file for bundle generation. Default is 'index.android.js' or 'index.js'
    // entryFile = file("../js/MyApplication.android.js")
    //
    //   A list of extra flags to pass to the 'bundle' commands.
    //   See https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/commands.md#bundle
    // extraPackagerArgs = []

    /* Hermes Commands */
    //   The hermes compiler command to run. By default it is 'hermesc'
    // hermesCommand = "$rootDir/my-custom-hermesc/bin/hermesc"
    //
    //   The list of flags to pass to the Hermes compiler. By default is "-O", "-output-source-map"
    // hermesFlags = ["-O", "-output-source-map"]
}


/**
 * Set this to true to Run Proguard on Release builds to minify the Java bytecode.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore (JSC)
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US. Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    
    // Obviously the namespace "example" is not the name actually used, is an example
    namespace "com.example"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release{
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }    
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: It is likely that your configured application ID and/or the authority ID assembled by your dependencies is not unique and is already in use by another developer (in Google's eyes - i.e. you might not be using the right signing certificate/account).

---

***Note:** This is a result of my own research on the build pipeline, the results of this research may not reach the correct conclusion. But as you haven't got an answer from anyone else yet, I'll at least post my research until a subject-matter expert can weigh in.*

---

As the documentation covers:

> **Important:** Once you publish your app, you should never change the application ID. If you change the application ID, Google Play Store treats the upload as a completely different app. If you want to upload a new version of your app, you must use the same application ID and [signing certificate](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) as when originally published.

Before reading on, its a good time to check you are publishing using the right Google account (e.g. work and personal accounts) and you also want to make sure you are using the same signing certificate used the last time you published (e.g. maybe used  a different computer).

---

If the above comments don't apply you can move on to checking your project's configuration.

You haven't specified which build tool you are using, so I'm going to assume you are following the [Android App Module](https://developer.android.com/build/configure-app-module) documentation and using a version of Gradle.

Your project's `build.gradle` file will look like this:

```
// this example is for Groovy (see link for Kotlin)
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp" // <-- this line is important
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

---

What is `applicationId`?

The `applicationId` value in that file dictates the perpetual ID of your app. As best practice, your application ID should be nested under a reversed web domain you own. If you intend to publish multiple apps, you also want to append a unique name for your application.

If you own `example.com`, you could use:

- `com.example` (valid, but not recommended unless you will only ever publish one main app)
- `com.example.android` (okay)
- `com.example.app` (okay, also useful if `app.example.com` is an actual website)
- `com.example.project` (okay, allows for different tiers/projects - e.g. `com.example.free`, `com.example.fitness`, or `com.example.lite`)
- `com.example.project.app` (ideal, particularly useful for client projects and grouping project components)

Looking at the RNFirebase library, you can see that they use `io.invertase.firebase.*` - `invertase.io` is their website, `firebase` is the project, then the particular component is added onto the end (e.g. `app`, `auth`, `firestore`, etc.).

---

How is the `applicationId` used?

When you compile your application, the `applicationId` you choose is added as an authority by the `AndroidManifest.xml` files of each of your compatible dependencies.

For example, these lines appear in [`AndroidManifest.xaml` of `firebase/firebase-android-sdk`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/dc48e69d216f4c1a15bd208a2e592ec64625d586/firebase-common/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L24):

```
<provider
  android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
  android:authorities="${applicationId}.firebaseinitprovider"
  android:directBootAware="true"
  android:exported="false"
  android:initOrder="100" />
```

A similar entry can be found in [`AndroidManifest.xaml` of `invertase/react-native-firebase`](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/c9b695aa8fd75d5a1d070ecbb6bb9ac4e9ff062e/packages/app/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L20):

```xml
<provider
  android:name="io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppInitProvider"
  android:authorities="${applicationId}.reactnativefirebaseappinitprovider"
  android:exported="false"
  android:initOrder="99" /> <!-- Firebase = 100, using 99 to run after Firebase initialises (highest first) -->
```

These lines allow these SDKs to pass data in and out of your app.

---

The error you see is derived from the presence of these provider entries. As the assembled provider ID in that authority field corresponds to a provider defined in an already published app, Google Play is preventing you from impersonating it. Importantly, such an app does not need to be publicly accessible, just registered with Google Play.

To correct this, you need to make sure you have the authority to update the existing app OR change your application ID and use your original `AndroidManifest.xml` as it is in your question. Based on your question, your current `applicationId` is `com.####`, consider changing it to `com.####.topic`, `com.####.app`, `com.####.chat`, etc.

Comment: Technically the solution of changing the name of the applicationId inside the build.gradle works, now Google Play Console doesn't give me any problems..

But changing the applicationId generates another rather strange problem, I don't understand why by changing the applicationId the application no longer starts, or rather it starts correctly for the first time, but if I stop the terminal and restart the app it remains in infinite limbo where it doesn't load the application in the Android Studio emulator. I'm forced every time to close Visual Studio Code and restart it to get it started.

Comment: This is the last part of the terminal's response when I try to start the app, where it remains in that infinite limbo that I mentioned before... practically just before starting the app correctly, it freezes:


"BUILD SUCCESSFUL in the 20s
439 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 437 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"...
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example/.MainActivity }"


Where obviously "com.example" is an example.
I'm trying to understand why this happens.